# Best way to load CSV files into SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, bcp, bulk

I've got a script that's scraping CSV files. Each day I get 36 individual CSV files, each with about 100 lines of data.

I want to load these into SQL Server 2008 each day. I've tried using Bulk Insert, but it doesn't like my CSV files very much, with inconsistent quotation marks.

I've just found out about `BCP.exe`, is that a good solution?

The CSV file looks like this (the top line is ignored)

```
24544,"1970-01-01 10:00:00","8056060 kWh"
24544,"2012-12-04 00:15:00",0.176
24544,"2012-12-04 00:30:00",0.163
24544,"2012-12-04 00:45:00",0.016
```

Comment: " it doesn't like....inconsistent quotation marks."  No one likes inconsistent quotation marks.  Whatever the solution, you will have to scrub your data.

Answer (score 0):

create a table first then execute the query

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest           -- the tableName
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'    -- file location
WITH  
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

- [Import CSV File Into SQL Server Using Bulk Insert – Load Comma Delimited File Into SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)

Comment: Hi, BULK INSERT doesn't like the date field being enclosed in quotation marks.